# При работе с json файлом через API вместо данных, получаю объект, как получить только данные?

Tags: json, fetch, promise

При работе с json файлом через API вместо данных, получаю объект, как получить только данные, которые находятся в -PromiseResult-

```
  getResourse = async (url) => {
let res = await fetch(url);
if (!res.ok) {
  throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${url}, status: ${res.status}`);
}
return await res.json().then(item => item.articles[2].author);
```

};

[image: При работе с json файлом через API вместо данных, получаю объект, как получить только данные, которые находятся в -PromiseResult-]

Comment: Результат в строку res.text()

Comment: Если я так понял